# How to insert data during many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

lets say we have two classes(these are just sample classses):

```
public class Post
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } 
}

public class Tag
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Label { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
}
```

**P.S after execution "PostTag" table is created in database.**

So in my current database there is the following situation: I have separate service for getting "**Posts**" and I am writing this data directly to database.**(lets say we have 500 records in database. P.S these are max number of "Posts" I will be working around)**.

Then I have service for "Tag". This service does the following: I am getting data of "Tags" from API**(It is about 1500 records)**, which is collection and each "Tag" contains its own "Post" collection in returned data **(lets say each "Tag" has 100 records of "Posts").**

So the problem is that, after I get all the "**Tags**" and then write them in database, in "**Post**" tables, "**Posts**" that was returned during "Tag" service are also written in table, I mean before calling "**Tag**" service, **If we had 500 records, now we have 15000 + 500 and that is wrong.**

I want to happen following: when I call "**Tag**" service, it should just write "**Tags**" in database table and instead of adding "**Posts**" in table, use already written data in "Posts" table in order to set up relationship in "**PostTag**" table.

**So in tables there should be this kind of situation: Post - 500 records, Tags - 1500 records and PostTag - the amount of records that are needed for relationship**

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

There a Problem with your entities

**Post** Table dont contain tags. but its will contain **PostTag** table id.

**Note** If you already have table PostTag in database. you can still map it by simply defining class in your dbcontext

```
 public class Post
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } 
    }
    
    public class Tag
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Label { get; set;}
        public virtual ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; } 
    }

public class PostTag
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
        public int TagId { get; set; }
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I thought about that but doesn't ef core automatically does that? i mean is it necessary to manually create join table and configure it?

Comment: @SabaMinashvili Ef actually does it. But sometimes it's don't match our use case. So

Answer (score 0):

If you have two entities with many-to-many relationship, you have to make a new class that connects the other two classes. You should include primary keys (of the other classes) and additional features that describe that connection (in most cases).

Comment: I thought about that but doesn't ef core automatically does that? i mean is it necessary to manually create join table and configure it?

Comment: Yes. It does it automatically but a better practice is doing it manually. Because in a project you gonna have multiple tables.

Comment: Okay but if i change in that way, it will cause another problems. I have provider classes that get data from api and then i map them in entities. If i make join tables, then i will have new type of properties in entities and how could i map provider classes in these entities?